# Splitting a value with comma in a csv file

Tags: python, csv, apache-beam, python-2.x

I am trying to split a csv file in python . But some of the value(in one cell) has comma in it . But the function is splitting it as well thus giving me more columns than expected.

Following is my code :

```
data = open('FInal_epm-00000-of-00001').read()
lines_of_data = data.splitlines()
tmp = []
for i in range(len(lines_of_data)):
    tmp.append(re.split('\',|, ',lines_of_data[i]))
```

Following is the sample input :

```
['string_value', 'string_value', int_value, float_value, 'string_val, string_val']
```

Ideal Output:

```
row 1 :string_value, string_value, int_value, float_value, 'string_val, string_val'
```

Output i am getting:

```
row 1 : string_value, string_value, int_value, float_value, string_val, string_val
```

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Use the csv module. Plenty of examples on SO.

Comment: That is literally an input line? Then its not a csv file at all. And what is a `int_value` anyway? A string that is literally those characters? And what about the output... you append to a list but your output is a line? We really need exactly what goes in and what goes out.

Comment: Yes it is an input line (it's a pcollection) and for int_value . You can assume any int value as I just wanted to say that the input data is mixture of string as well as it value .

Comment: It would be better to just post an input line instead of some pseudocode kinda describing what the data is kinda like. What you posted is not CSV. If int_value is just a placeholder for an integer that we are supposed to fill in ... do that for us! For instance, an example could be `"foo,bar,20,1.222,'baz, qux'"` with desired output being a python list `["foo", "bar", 20, 1.222, "baz, qux"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). It will take care of all of that for you!